# How to Set Checkbox Checked if Value Is Yes (Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a form which I am prefilling through a GET request. I am setting the value of a checkbox to either `Yes` or `No`. I would like to set the checkbox to `checked` if the value is `Yes`.

script

```
<script>
    if ($('#cisco').val() == 'Yes') {
        $('#cisco').prop('checked', true);
    }
</script>
```

form.html

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cisco" id="cisco"
                   value="{{ request.GET.cisco }}">Cisco:
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the script above or below your div tag?

Comment: @Taplar The script is below the div tag.

Comment: And you say you are prefilling it through a GET request?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Taplar the value of the checkbox is pulled from a GET request `{{ request.get.cisco }}`, which is working fine. I want to compare the value and if it is `Yes`, set the checkbox to checked.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because when you say "GET request" that makes me think you are performing some ajax request to get the data.  Is this accurate?

Comment: @Taplar I am using Django/Python, so the GET request is performed in my view and rendered to my template.html.

Comment: So is this done *before* the html is returned to the client? Because if so, then that's not really relevant to the issue.  If it is done on the client side, after the html is returned to the client, then this would be an async issue.

Comment: @Taplar correct, it is handled before. Perhaps tying the checkbox to a function would work? Or am I comparing the value correctly?

Comment: Your jQuery script, if it is below your div as you say it is, is fine.  `console.log($('#cisco').val())` immediately before the if and see what it logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an if else statement in the HTML. You don't need the javascript.

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="control">
    <label class="checkbox">

      {% if request.GET.cisco == "Yes" %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="cisco" id="cisco" checked> Cisco:
      {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="cisco" id="cisco"> Cisco:
      {% endif %}

    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you inline it?  `{%= request.GET.cisco == "Yes" ? 'checked' : '' %}` ?  (I'm not familiar with this templating but other templating tags like this have similiar behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax for the inline, but the if else statement worked nicely. Thank you both!

Comment: you can't inline it in Django templating system so you have to do it the way i described above, unfortunately :(